# Set ToolBar label in Manifest or activity.xml

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I keep seeing my domain name in the ToolBar in the past I would just use the Manifest file with this line android:label="@string/app_name" I can accomplish this in the ActivityMain.java with title. but would prefer to use the xml and strings concept. The only thing I have done different is create a custom style in the styles.xml for some TextView widgets tools v 24.0.2 V7 24.2.0 code posted

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<!--<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>-->

<style name="MyStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#f10909</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:width">190dp</item>
</style>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.XXX.newstyletest">

<application>
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:title="what the Hell"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/MyStyle">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Is this an issue because of the custom style of has something changed ?
or what the heck am I doing wrong

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screen shot of your toolbar?

Comment: Where do you set `app_name`?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using `applicationId` on accident?

Comment: Please show the line from your `strings.xml` file that defines the string resource named `app_name`.

Comment: You should also try adding a custom style to the Hello, World app.

Comment: That's very strange. If I have some time later this weekend, I'll look into this more.

Comment: Hey James, I might have something for you but could you clarify your problem a bit more, I'm just having a bit of trouble understanding. Correct me if I'm wrong but you are saying that you keep seeing "com.your.domain" as the toolbar title, and that you can successfully change this by using toolbar.setTitle("Hello World"), however, you cannot accomplish this through the manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to scream when you SEE what is wrong if you look real close at you AndroidManifest.xml file you will see you have a situation where the code below the  is UNREACHABLE because you have a closing brace behind the word application So just remove that **>** and life will be good

Comment: The app wouldn't build if that was included. Probably a typo

Comment: @user2475470 You are in need of a new user name I like the Greridel we have been reading about BeoWulf YES this is my SCREAM good eye as a 7th grader I make some real simple mistakes Consider the answer up-voted ha ha